# Transformer - 2 Wires in and 3 wires out - How to connect ground?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, power-electronics, rectifier, linear-regulator

I have the following transformer:
[image: 220 to Dual 24 Volt 50Hz Transformer]

And the following power cable:
[image: 3 Prong Power Cable with Ground Pin Asia-Pacific]

This is for a dual-polarity power supply for some audio circuits. How should I connect the ground pin to this circuit? Can the transformer I have be used to build this?
[image: LM317/LM337 Dual Polarity Power Supply]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transformer should be bolted to the chassis of your project and connect ground from our mains to the chassis.  I you are using a plastic project box, it will likely be best to connect to a bolt you are using to mount the transformer to the plastic box.  That way, if you ever fry your transformer and you develop a short to the transformer chassis, you'll immediately pop your circuit breaker (and hopefully the fuse in your project).

Yes, your transformer is fine, the two mains wires connect to the two red wires of your transformer.  The three wire bundle will become your input to the power supply - two blue to the bridge rectifier and yellow is the circuit "ground".  I would NOT connect circuit ground of your project to your Mains Ground until you run some tests and make sure everything is ok. After that, it really depends what you plan t use it for whether you want to connect to ground.  F you are just learning to use an oscilloscope, I would not connect to ground until you understand how your scope works and the ground reference of your scope.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response! So, the third wire of the power cable also be connected to the chassis, and the transformer also connected to the same chassis, right? On the secondary side, the center tap of the transformer becomes the ground point for the circuit, which is NOT connected to mains ground. Is that correct?

Comment: If he doesn't connect the secondary centre tap to ground, his grounding relies on accidental grounding of audio connectors.

Comment: @ianbland yes, you are right but it sounds to me like he is in earning mode rather than making audio equipment to connect to his receiver or tape deck.

Comment: I agree @IanBland . Surely in the final circuit, the centre tap should go to the centre pin of the PSU. Ok, often you want a floating secondary in test equipment, but it's clear the circuit given expects a grounded centre tap or why would it be presented at J2?

Comment: @DanSheppard it really depends on what kind of audio he want to do (play, experiment, test vs connecting to a mains powered audio system vs other) - hopefully the OP can let us know what he wants to do.

Comment: @DavidGraham what is your target output voltage?

Comment: @DavidGraham yes, we understand correctly but, it really depends how you plan to use the power supply.  If you are using it for an amp connected to a mains powered CD, tape player or whatever, you'll eventually want to connect mains ground to your power supply ground.

Comment: @IanBland I am not the OP, don't ask me.

Comment: @GTElectronics sorry, corrected :)

Comment: You are right that I am in learning mode. It's more experimental so far than creating equipment to connect to ready made equipment. What about putting a switch on the ground on the secondary side to "float it" (between the secondary center tap and the pcb)?

Comment: This is a power supply for learning audio transistor circuits, powering dual polarity op amps, and getting more fluent in using transistors in general. I am looking for +/- 24 volts.

Comment: It's better to hard wire it since a) you won't always remember where the switch is set.  And (b) you'll want much more current carrying capacity than most switches so keep it solid.

Comment: @DavidGraham note the edit in my Answer about your capacitors C9 and C10 being shorted to ground. Should those shorting links be connected to the other pin on your potentiometer?

Comment: If you use a 12VAC transformer, with rectification, it will be about +/-16 volts unregulated. This is a good voltage for op amps.  Dealing with +/-24v dc means dealing with large voltage drops and heat as you regulate voltages down for projects that need less voltage.  Voltage will sag below 16v under moderate loads but not for simple op amp circuitry.

Comment: 48V (+-24) will blow up most ordinary op amps. I concur about either using a lower voltage as @GTElectronics says. I'd have separate experimental power supplies for lower and higher voltage circuits.

Comment: That's good advice regarding separate power supplies for sure. That makes sense. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @ Ian Bland - I'm not sure why those capacitors are there specifically. I am building this from a schematic that I found elsewhere.

Comment: It's not the capacitors, it's the connections  from wiper to ground that is an issue.

Comment: In fact C7 and C3 (and their counterparts) are simply in parallel as well, what are the suggested values? I don't trust this schematic at all.

Comment: I agree. Kind of a hack.

Comment: Look at page 13 on this Texas Instruments doc.  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snvs778e/snvs778e.pdf?ts=1642963399240&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Note: this type of power supply gets quite hot when it is set to output low voltages. And the more current at low voltage, the hotter those regulators will get.

Comment: Thank you for that wonderful datasheet. I think I am going to try to rework this schematic and post it again. Unfortunately, I am not entirely sure why they are arranged that way, I was just somewhat following the schematic. Perhaps I should simulate it in LT spice (on Mac) first and see what it does?

Comment: As far as the heat is concerned, in the protoboard LM317 version I built I used thermal grease and a big aluminum heat sink, but didn't try pulling much current with it. What's the best way to test the temperature of a component under load? (A specific tool / analytical method?)

Comment: A specific tool?  Your finger should work for a start but the part can get much hotter and still be fine to temperatures much higher than your finger can handle. If you have an LM35 and a volt meter, a meat thermometer, a thermocouple.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your audio circuits ground referenced- you probably do- the centre tap of the secondary (output side) connects to Earth, as does your safety Earth in the mains lead. The primary goes across Live and Neutral.

I've just noticed your capacitors C9 and C10 are shorted to ground!

*edit* following the discussions, I would suggest a "bog standard" linear power supply design, this one turns up first on my search and is the kind of thing

https://www.eleccircuit.com/power-supply-regulator-15v-15v-1a-by-ic-7815-7915/

It's a fixed 15-0-15. For 12-0-12 just use 7812/7912 regulators. They're dirt cheap and have automatic output shorting protection, which is good working with experimental circuits.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why those capacitors are there specifically. I am building this from a schematic that I found elsewhere.

Comment: Looking at the datasheet, there are no capacitors shown in that position in the reference circuit and you can probably do without. They are presumably intended to smooth the potentiometer output but cant because they're shorted. The pot is shown as a reference *current* not voltage. Take a look at the datasheet, I'd follow that reference application circuit myself.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to rework the think. Thanks for that reference circuit that you sent me. It looks like there are some other goodies there, also. May I ask, with a max current output of greater than or equal to 1amp, why is the linked circuit fused at .5 amp on the primary side?) Shouldn't it be fused at 1 amp?

Comment: Also, does the LMxxx short circuiting protection take care of fusing on the +/- 15 V outputs or should those also be fused?

Comment: @DavidGraham The 0.5A fuse is to protect the circuit from emitting smoke if the transformer primary shorts out. The current draw is actually much lower than that (remember, when you step down the voltage on the secondary, you proportionally reduce the current on the primary) but there is some inrush current when the transformer starts. The fuse is basically just short circuit protection. The LMxxx's output protection will protect everything downstream from shorts. You wouldn't normally bother fusing on the secondary side of a low power circuit like this.

Comment: Is there a specific type of fuse that should be used?

Comment: Yes, use a "slow blow" type.

Answer (score 0):

You never want to conduct line frequency rectifier current through PE ground as this adds conductive noise.  Using the transformer for high impedance and insulation from high voltage transients gives the audio better common mode noise rejection ratios (CMRR).

Grounding is used for noise reduction when it stays at the same voltage by not forcing noise current thru it but rather providing a low impedance reference to high impedance stray noise ingress thus attenuation occurs in shielded audio lines or low impedance speaker drivers.

There are occasions where RF can create audio noise in preamps so a capacitor can suppress this to the audio power 0V whether that is PE grounded or not.

Thus when using PE ground for computer audio, realize the PC power supply uses CM chokes and lots of filtering so that there is minimal audio band noise current on PE ground. Expect all peripherals to be floating and then rely on the host  only for PE ground to suppress radiated noise thru the network or shielded cables.

When multiple source and destinations use PE grounds, you can get the "ground loop"  noise due to the difference in ground voltage and current that caused that.

The term "ground" simply means 0V locally whereever you define that reference point.

Safety or Protective Earth (PE) ground is 0V in the earth and close enough elsewhere to be safe.  So with interconnections you don't want to add noise current when audio is interconnected. The current should only be the intended audio.